# How can i access fragment layout in parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gridview, baseadapter

I have got a tabpager and fragments. And a frament has got a "GridView". I am using a **basedapter innerclass** in the fragment parent activity.

But when i want to set adapter to my gridview i m getting **nullpointerexception**. Because GridView variable is always null.how can solve this issue?

Fragment Parent MainActivity OnCreate Method;

```
GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview); // debugging and always null
gv.setAdapter(new AdapterB(this,WallPaperList));
```

Fragment xml

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

MyGrid.xml  (For populate with adapter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagepart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seç"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant acces fragment views like that, becouse they could be not yet in the activity view hierarchy.

You have to add some method to your fragment, like

```
myCustomFragment.setGridAdapter(MyCustomGridViewAdapter adapter)
```

and in this method in your custom fragment:

```
public void setGridAdapter(){
    this.myCustomGridAdapter = adapter;
    GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview); 

    if(gv != null)
        gv.setAdapter(this.myCustomGridAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Even though fragments **might** not be in the activity's view hierarchy, `findViewById` finds views in the activity's window. Therefore you can find the views from fragments as long as they are already inflated.

Comment: Then i must write all code fragment java class am i correct ? Or is there any solution can find fragment view in mainactivity class?

Comment: You wonder if u need to implement custom fragment class? - Yes

Comment: Then i must ask question again here. How can i send main activity context to in fragment class to my adapter inner class ?

Comment: if u invoke this method when the fragment is attached to your activity, that u can get activity by getActivity() method, but if u pass adapter before your fragment will be attached to activity, u must check for it, and do all work in onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview); // debugging and always null
gv.setAdapter(new AdapterB(this,WallPaperList));
```

should be inside of your fragment's `onCreateView`. You should create fragments that are independent from the activity they're attached to.

If you absolutely need to access the fragment's layout from your activity you need to delay the `findViewById` because the fragment's layout is not yet inflated when you call it:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv.setAdapter(new AdapterB(this, WallPaperList));
    }
}, 1000);
```

Although this code would work, I highly discourage you from using it!

Comment: Then i must ask question again here. How can i send main activity context to in fragment class to my adapter inner class ?

Comment: @EmreErol do you mean `getActivity()`?